How to Restore a MongoDB Database with its users and indexes under a different database name?
I have two MongoDB clusters: DEV and PRO. For backup purposes, I use mongodump to export each and every database from the PRO cluster, including users, indexes, and roles:
mongodump --host "<PRO_CLUSTER>" --dumpDbUsersAndRoles ...

When I restore the database example1 from the PRO cluster into the DEV cluster, everything works as expected: all collections, documents, users, and indexes are restored correctly.
mongorestore -d example1 --restoreDbUsersAndRoles --host "<DEV_CLUSTER>" backup_pro_example1.tar.gz

However, if I try to restore the backup under a different database name, e.g: example2, while collections and documents are restored correctly, users and indexes are missing.
mongorestore -d example2 --restoreDbUsersAndRoles --host "<DEV_CLUSTER>" backup_pro_example1.tar.gz

How can I work around this issue to ensure users and indexes are also restored when restoring to a different database name?

Did you try --nsFrom and --nsTo option? Do you have any log output?

When you use --dumpDbUsersAndRoles then most likely you have authentication enabled. You don't specify any user credentials, thus most likely you have no privileges to read any data, roles or users. Thus I am a bit surprised when you say, it works for the same database. How do you deal with roles if the database names are different? The role may not work anymore with different database name.
